# How can I activate the text preview in Finder's column view for an arbitrary filetype or document type

Tags: finder, quicklook

I really like the preview functionality that Finder offers in the last column of the column view. However, not all filetypes or document types are associated with a preview.

For example when I have a file *INSTALL* (without file extension), the document type of this file is just *Document* and the preview column only contains an icon.

How do I change the behavior of Finder in such a way that a text preview is displayed for the file *INSTALL*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column previews in Finder are in fact provided by [QuickLook](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.7/en/mh14119.html), not Preview – as are the icons displaying the file contents, the CoverFlow icons and the QuickLook preview proper you invoke by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd+Y</kbd> on a selected file.

QuickLook uses *plugins* to display file contents – a piece of code rendering the file contents and telling the QuickLook server it can do so (see the [QuickLook Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/) if you want the technical details). You need plugins because files can be binary data – without knowledge of its structure, no representation of the file is possible – or textual data that needs processing – HTML for instance, which you’ll probably prefer to preview rendered, not as raw source. They also must be limited to specific, known file types (to be precise: [Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/), or UTIs for short) for this exact reason – a rendering plugin for HTML will not give you a usable preview for a JPEG. OS X provides quite an impressive default collection of these plugins (located in `/System/Library/QuickLook`), and applications you install add their own (located in the application package itself, `/Library/QuickLook` or `~/Library/QuickLook`). You can also add some yourself to those two last locations.

In the case of text files without an extension, the problem is OS X’s built-in plain-text QuickLook plugin is not assigned to these as they do not correspond to a UTI it handles. However, there is a 3rd party QuickLook plugin adding that functionality: [QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.com/qlstephen/). Just download it and install it according to its installation instructions [on GitHub](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen#readme) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The QLStephen package now allows me to obtain a preview of the _INSTALL_ file by pressing the space bar in Finder. However, the last column in the column view still displays the icon only. Is there a fix for that, too?

Comment: @Christian: Ah, drat, no – thumbnails and full previews are created in different routines. Annoyingly QLStephen only does the latter, the former is but [a non-functional stub in the code](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/blob/master/QuickLookStephenProject/GenerateThumbnailForURL.m). Sorry, I missed that when answering.

Comment: @Christian: if I can find the time, I’ll fork the project and add that part. Update for 64 bit, too – better for Lion. Don’t hold your breath for that, tho.